# How can I access html in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to make a href link can access sub.html of Django app.
I wrote in index.html like

```
<p class="button"><a href="{% static 'templates/sub.html'%}">Next</a></p>
```

but when I put Next button,Page not found (404) 
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/templates/sub.html error happens.
My app's structure is

```
-app
 -index
  -templates
   -index.html
   -sub.html
  -urls.py
  -views.py
 -manage.py
```

What is wrong in my codes?I rewrote `<a href="{% static 'sub.html'%}">` but same error happens.How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static files are for stylesheets javascript and other static documents.
you can add a template as view in your urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('sub/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='sub.html'), name='sub')
]
```

Then in your `index.html` template:
    `<p class="button"><a href="{% url 'suub' %}">Next</a></p>`

Comment: thank you for your answer.In this time,I want to access to sub.html by ajax.So,I did not want to change url.Can your way access to sub.html by ajax?

Comment: in your answer codes,is foo.html  equal index.html?

Comment: foo.html is for sub.html

Answer (score 0):

You must refer to urls and then urls refer to views and after that view render html tamplate

If you using name attribute in url like `path('url',views.yourview,name='yourname')` then you can use:

```
{%  url 'your name'   %}
```

in your template

Example:

```
<a href='{% url 'yourname'  %}'>Link</a>
```